# Displaying a shuffled integer array in java

Tags: java, arrays

sorry I'm really new to all of this. I know this is a stupid/easy question, but how would I display the shuffled array after i've set it all up. I have my code below and made the class that creates the array and has the algorithm for shuffling the integers inside the array. But I can't figure out how to display the shuffled array. Heres my code below:

My main:

```
package lab4b;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class Lab4B {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Shuffler test = new Shuffler(15);



       test.Shuffle();
       test.display();



    }

}
```

and my Shuffle class:

```
package lab4b;
import java.security.SecureRandom;


public class Shuffler {
    private static final SecureRandom randomNumbers = new SecureRandom();
    private int [] data;

    public Shuffler (int size){

       data = new int [size];
       for(int i = 0; i<data.length;i++){
        data[i]= i+1;
       }

    }

public void Shuffle(){
int temp;
for(int first = 0; first<data.length; first++){

int second = randomNumbers.nextInt(data.length);

temp = data[first];
data[first] = data[second];
data[second] = temp;

}





}

public void display()

{

    for(int counter =0; counter<data.length; counter++ ){

    System.out.print(data[counter]+ "  ");



    }
    System.out.println();
}  



}
```

Comment: Don't modify `data[counter]` **before** you `print` it.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch so you're saying don't do the  "Counter + 1" part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this loop you are reset the value of the `data`array

```
for(int counter =0; counter<data.length; counter++ ){
   // data[counter] = counter + 1;   - do not do this
   System.out.print(data[counter]+ "  ");
}
```

Comment: I've fixed it, is that better

Comment: Okay, guys thanks a lot! This worked. The problem is, I'm not sure why that didn't work. What do you mean i reset the value? I want to really understand this

Comment: In your loop you were doing `data[counter] = counter + 1`  - in the first loop of your loop this would be the same as doing `data[0] = 1`, the second time `data[1] = 2` etc.

Comment: Ah ok. So if I'm understanding it right, in this context i would need to run a loop that would create the values in the array..as i did in the constructor. Then another loop that would display the array using the counter loop. Is that right?

Comment: That's what you are doing.

Comment: It says i need to have a total of 15 reputation points to up vote, but i accepted the answer.